# Passing a pointer to an array of structures

Tags: c, pointers

I am having issues with a book assignment that I have been working on, hoping to get some help. My program compiles without issue, but when I run it, I get

```
First time through: (null)
After: 0000000
First time through: (null)
After: 1111111
```

When I insert a hash it checks to see if that array value has already been assigned. If it does, it prints "Collision detected" and it creates a new node and links it to the previous node. Right now it seems like its an automatic variable even though I am passing it a pointer?

I am pretty sure it has to do with how I am declaring my array of structures and passing them into insert_hash, but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

```
struct hash_node
{
    char *data;
    struct hash_node *next;

};

struct hash_node *create_table(int size);
unsigned int hash(const char *str);
void insert_hash(const char *str, const char *value, struct hash_node *h);

int
main(void)
{   
    struct hash_node *table = create_table(101);

    insert_hash("testing", "0000000", table);
    insert_hash("testing", "1111111", table);


}

struct hash_node
*create_table(int size)
{
    struct hash_node *table = calloc(size, sizeof(*table));

    if(!table)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return table;
}

unsigned int
hash(const char *str)
{
    unsigned int c, hash;

    while ((c = *str++))
    {
        hash += c;
    }

    hash = hash % 100;

    return hash;
}

void
insert_hash(const char *str, const char *value,  struct hash_node *h)
{
    int temp = hash(str);

    printf("First time through: %s\n", h[temp].data);

    if (h[temp].data)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Collision detected\n");

        struct hash_node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(*node));

        if (!node)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
            return;
        }

        node -> data = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
        strncpy(node -> data, value, strlen(value) + 1);

        node->next = NULL;

        h[temp].next = node;
    }
    else
    {

        h[temp].data = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
        strncpy(h[temp].data, value, strlen(value) + 1);
    }

    printf("After: %s\n", h[temp].data);

}
```

Comment: I think you mean struct hash_node *table = calloc(size, sizeof(table)); or truct hash_node **table = calloc(size, sizeof(*table));

Comment: *"My program compiles without issue..."* Um, no.  Try compiling with warnings enabled. For gcc or clang use `-Wall`.

Comment: You also need to describe the problem that you're having. I don't see anything wrong with the output you've shown.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I had Wall enabled but when I added all my other flags I saw the errors.

Comment: @AmiNo `printf("First time through: %s\n", h[temp].data);` is undefined behaviour, because `h[temp].data` is `NULL`, it may sometimes print `(null)` and it may sometimes crash.

Comment: You're still not seeing the only warning that matters, or at least you didn't fix it in the code. What compiler are you using? And what is the command line that you're using?

Comment: @Pablo Thanks for your feedback. I understand thats why NULL is printing. But I should be seeing collision detected on the second iteration of insert_hash am I correct?

Comment: @user3386109  gcc -o hash hash.c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 -Wstack-usage=512 -Wfloat-equal -Waggregate-return -Winline -Wwrite-strings -g

Comment: @AmiNo have you checked that `hash(str)` always returns the same for the same input?

Comment: @Pablo I just checked and I am getting different values back, which Is weird. I'll have to look into that, thanks! EDIT: Looks like initializing hash to 0 cleared that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hash` function is wrong

```
unsigned int
hash(const char *str)
{
    unsigned int c, hash;   //<--- not initialized

    while ((c = *str++))
    {
        hash += c;
    }

    hash = hash % 100;

    return hash;
}
```

The `hash` variable is **not** initialized, so it has an undefined value every
time you execute it. Initialize it with 0:

```
unsigned int
hash(const char *str)
{
    unsigned int c, hash = 0;

    while ((c = *str++))
    {
        hash += c;
    }

    hash = hash % 100;

    return hash;
}
```

Then I get

```
First time through: (null)
After: 0000000
First time through: 0000000
Collision detected
After: 0000000
```

---

**edit**

In case of a collision you are also not appending the new node correctly. You
first have to find the end of the list and then append the new node at the end
of the list:

```
node *tail = h[temp].next;

while(tail->next)
    tail = tail->next;


struct hash_node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(*node));
...

tail->next = node;
```

Or you can preprend the new node at the beginning of the list

```
struct hash_node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(*node));
...

node->next = h[temp].next;
h[temp].next = node;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!